# What is the formal name of the Library in the Hellflower trilogy?

Tags: character-identification, hellflower-series

I'm asking about the main Library who is the companion of ButterflysareFree in the [Hellflower](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1214718.Hellflower) series by [eluki bes shahar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosemary_Edghill).

It's been so long, I've forgotten, but it is "The Library at...", where the missing word is the planet of origin, which as I recall, was the capital of the dead empire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not find a preview of the book online, but the reprint of Hellflower (Butterfly and Hellflower) is referenced in [Promise the Infinite by Robert Richart](https://books.google.co.za/books?id=Z98-DAAAQBAJ&pg=PA16&lpg=PA16&dq=University%20Library%20at%20Sikander%20Prime%20Paladin&source=bl&ots=-9JeSNB690&sig=dTrj6OH8aGnXheTkMkohBRPIsOw&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=University%20Library%20at%20Sikander%20Prime%20Paladin&f=false):

> Paladin is the name of a "Library", a black box which was once the **Library Main Bank Seven of the Federation University Library at Sikander Prime**. Now Paladin is installed on a starship owned by **Butterflies-are-free Peace Sincere**, known as Butterfly for short.

Answer (score 2):

The library, a long-lived AI has adopted the name **"*Paladin*".** It was originally **Library Main Bank Seven of
the Federation University Library at Sikander Prime**.

> *I am not human. I am not a machine. **I am Library Main Bank Seven of
> the Federation University Library at Sikander Prime**, an honor-able
> estate.*
>
> *At least I was. **Now I am Paladin, a new name for a new age.** Many of my
> books are gone from my memory. The world in which I lived is gone. My
> “friends” and “relatives” are all a millennium dead, and the
> profession for which I was trained no longer exists. I run Firecat, a
> converted intrasystem shuttle used for smuggling. I pursue researches
> for books I will never write, that no one would understand. Without
> Butterfly, there would not even be that much to occupy me.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Butterfly and Hellflower #1 - Hellflower](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/639873.Butterfly_and_Hellflower)</sup></sub>